# two markers in ionic native geolocation using cordova geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a scenario where I need to show the source and destination with two markers and a blue line that indicates directions. I am using cordava plugin geolocation and trying to get the current location like below

```
        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: $scope.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng
  });
```

I also have destination lat and long but I dnt understand how to place them in the code to show two markers and where to show blue connecting line

as

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: $scope.map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: latLng
});
```

takes only an object

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tania, did you try?

Answer (score 0):

What i did-

```
  addMarker(position, icon, content) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: icon,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(position[0], position[1])
    }); 
  }
```

And then

```
 array.projectsLocation.forEach(element => {
      this.addMarker([element.latitude, element.longitude], element.map_pin_url, element.description);
 });
```

I was using custom icons so you can ignore that.

Check [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers).